# How to establish a MySQL database connection in WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to setup WordPress on Ubuntu 14.04 following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial. Editing `wp-config.php`, I ran into `"Error establishing a database connection"` error.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'wordpressuser');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

Values for `DB_NAME`,`DB_USER` and `DB_PASSWORD` are correct. I'm unsure of `DB_HOST`; I've tried :

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306');
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.1.1');
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.1.1:3306');
define('DB_HOST', '159.203.70.104');
define('DB_HOST', '159.203.70.104:3306');
```

But none resolved the issue. MySQL and Apache logs show nothing about the error. MySQL shell output :

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6291
Server version: 5.5.55-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| wordpress          |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select User,Host from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------------------------------+
| User             | Host                              |
+------------------+-----------------------------------+
| root             | 127.0.0.1                         |
| root             | ::1                               |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost                         |
| root             | localhost                         |
| wordpressuser    | localhost                         |
| root             | npvr-vivek-2016-10-17-4gb-nyc3-01 |
+------------------+-----------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Restarting MySQL doesn't help. Shell output for `wordpressuser` :

```
mysql -u wordpressuser -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6646
Server version: 5.5.55-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| wordpress          |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: wordpressuser is available to connect only to localhost so if you try with 127.0.0.1 it will fail. Try adding 127.0.0.1 as host for the user and use the ip in the configuration file

Comment: do you see that you have two entry for user root? One with localhost as Host and one with 127.0.0.1 as host. Since these are two completely different methods to connect you need two entries also for your wp user. Add the new entry and then you should be able to work with 127.0.0.1 in the config file for wp

Comment: i'm telling you to add an entry with user= wordpressuser and host=127.0.0.1

Comment: after doing so edit the config file and change DB_HOST to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix by doing:

Create a new user:

```
CREATE USER 'wordpressuser'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

(change 'password') to your password

Grant this user rights on the wordpress db:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress . * TO 'newuser'@'127.0.0.1';
```

Finally use 127.0.0.1 as db host by editing the config file:

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.1.1');
```

You cannot use 127.0.0.1 as db host if the user has no auth to use it